# Vernier to Arduino not working

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, temperature-sensor

I want to connect this [analog Vernier temperature probe](https://www.vernier.com/product/stainless-steel-temperature-probe/) to my Arduino with this [British Telecom Connector (BTA)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12753).

According to datasheet, when sensor is in the connector, the PIN 6 of the connector should give us the value from 0-5V. I think it should work with this connector because it is supposed to work with [this adapter](https://www.vernier.com/product/analog-protoboard-adapter/), which is approved by Vernier. It's hard to get any real details about this official Vernier adapter, but I think it doesn't do anything different than just the BTA (linked above).

Of course, I also connected 5V and GND to connector, but when I want to read that 0-5V from Arduino, it says 0. Every single time. The sensor is not broken, because it works with Vernier sensor interface shield which I put on the Arduino (yes, I could use it, but I want to make my project smaller).

That's how the PINS work:

| Sensor Pin | Arduino Pin |
| --- | --- |
| 1 (+/-10 V output line) | A1 |
| 2 (Ground) | Ground |
| 3 (Vres/resistance reference) | A4 (also for I2C autoID) |
| 4 (AutoID) | A5 (also for I2C autoID) |
| 5 (+5 Volt power) | 5V |
| 6 (0-5 V output line) | A0 |

I don't know if that's important, but the sensor is based on a thermistor. Also, if I connect `A0` to PIN number 1 (+/- 10V output line), it gives me a value.  But, I really can't find anywhere how is that value connected with temperature. I hope I presented my problem well enough so you will understand it.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is probably going to sound mean, but I'm sincere in this. Break that up into coherent paragraphs and make sure you're focusing on one thing.

Comment: `data is a number that's not 0` ... very normal

Comment: Sorry, i just didn't know what kind of information do you need :/. That's the link to the probe: https://www.vernier.com/product/stainless-steel-temperature-probe/ . I though it would work with Arduino like this because it works if you use this protoboard adapter approved by Vernier: https://www.vernier.com/product/analog-protoboard-adapter/ .

Comment: Take some time to [edit your question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/81393/edit).  You can put those links into it while you're in there.

Comment: Well, I've made an edit to get you started.  I'm trying to be conservative with it.  You should refine it.